# Create new user group in Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal, account

With the need of create new user, I perform with the link below:

http://osxdaily.com/2007/10/29/how-to-add-a-user-from-the-os-x-command-line-works-with-leopard/

It works great.

But how to create new group?

Comment: Flagged as: I think this is generally an important question and it is a pity it rots here as closed / off-topic. Please move it to AskDifferent.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"System preferences" -> "Accounts" -> "+" (as if you were adding new account) -> Under "New account" select "Group" -> Type in group name -> "Create group"

Check this link from server fault
https://serverfault.com/questions/131942/how-do-i-add-a-group-in-mac-os-x-10-6