# XAMPP on mac os - Apache won't start

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I know this gets asked a lot but still, I wasn't able to find a solution.

I'm on Mac os and I'm trying to start Apache on XAMPP.

I tried `sudo apachectl stop` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582504/xampp-apache-webserver-localhost-not-working-on-mac-os) but that didn't work.

Terminal says `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service`.

The XAMPP Application Log says

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
apache config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
AH00544: httpd: bad group name Barbara
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can't stop what isn't running. and it won't run until you create a user group named `Barbara`, or tell apache to run as another group that already exists.

Comment: Thank you! It makes more sense now. Do you know where and how to create such user group? Or can you point me to some instructions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519663/create-new-user-group-in-mac-os

Comment: OMG, thank you!! I'm new to mac and this was driving me crazy. Can you made this into an answer so I can upvote you?

Answer (score 5):

if there is not a plist running that means apache is not running 
some times people already have apache running and then try and us xampp. now they try and run apache in two places on the same Mac. the plist tells you its not up and running so I would suggest trying to start the apache you want.

for xampp stack try this in terminal

sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start

Comment: Upvoted! I dont know why this answer was never upvoted. Thanks